# Running WSL command from C++ code over windows

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running c++ code in windows from which I want to run the commands on the wsl.

Here are the commands:

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "cmd", "bash -c \"rm -f /tmp/xyz.log\"" , NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

and,

```
system("start \"bash -c \"rm -f /tmp/xyz.log\"\"");
```

I tried both of the above but it doesn't work. Although these commands work on the WSL command prompt.

Comment: You've bash in Windows? Why are you not using `del` command?

Comment: I have a specific requirement of running the shell script from the C++ code running on windows. So that required me to run this over the cmd prompt using the WSL, I am trying to do the same

Comment: I would expect there to be a way to run through `wsl.exe` (like in a Windows prompt) but you probably need to know more about Windows than I do to get that working...

Comment: @user1867087: Right. Your `wsl.exe` paths are set, right?

Comment: @user1867087: Did you try `wsl args...` or `cmd wsl arg...`?

Comment: @user1867087 The executable is `wsl` or `bash`, not `cmd`. You don't need to open a Windows command line to start another. You don't need the shell's help to start an executeable either. You can just `system("bash -c \"rm -f /tmp/xyz.log\"")` or `ShellExecuteA(NULL, NULL, "bash", "-c \"rm -f /tmp/xyz.log\"" , NULL, SW_SHOW)`.  Note the `NULL` command. You aren't executing a shell command with a file, you are starting an executable directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos system throws an error saying "bash is not recognized as an internal or external command" and your second function ShellExecute fails with a return code 2. I already tried these 2.

Comment: @user1867087 that doesn't mean that going through the console or the shell will work. *Can you run wsl or bash at all ?*.

Comment: @Azeem yes they should be right because when I write wsl on the cmd prompt it switches to wsl

Comment: @user1867087 that's not what happens. You are *executing* `wsl.exe`. You don't need `cmd`. If you tried `system("wsl")` or `system("bash")` and failed, it may just be that the function needs the full path. `bash` is a shim to wsl.exe. `wsl.exe` can be found in `C:\Windows\System32`. You can verify this if you start `wsl` from the `Windows Run` dialog, open Task Manager and check the file location of `wsl`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I can run the commands like bash -c "uname -a" thorough dos cmd prompt also

Comment: @user1867087 I'll bet you are targeting x86 instead of x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate this and run into this problem immediately. After (quite) a bit of confusion, I found [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1105) and realized my test project was targeting x86 instead of x64 . Duh ...

`wsl.exe` and `bash.exe` are 64-bit files, stored in `c:\Windows\System32`. If you try running them from an x86 application they appear to be missing. That's because Windows shows a *different*, 32-bit specific `c:\Windows\System32` folder to 32-bit applications. The 64-bit System32 folder will appear under `C:\Windows\Sysnative`.

The easy solution is to change the target to x64. Once that's done, even

```
system("wsl ls -la");
```

or

```
system("bash -c ls -la");
```

Just work.

For x86 applications the solution is to use the absolute path in `Sysnative`, eg :

```
system("c:/windows/sysnative/bash -c ls -la");
```

or

```
system("c:/windows/sysnative/wsl -c ls -la");
```